# Password is empty after retrieving credentials from PasswordVault

Tags: c#, passwords, uwp, credentials

I'm using a `PasswordVault` to store user' login/password in Windows 10 UWP application. When I grab login/password from server I store then in vault using this code:

```cs
PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
vault.Add(new PasswordCredential(key, login, password));
```

Now when I want to retrieve these credentials from vault I use next code:

```
PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
vault.FindAllByResource(key).ToList();
```

But unfortunately `Password` property inside my `PasswordCredential` instance retrieved from `PasswordVault` is empty all the time. I use the right key, `Username` property is stored correctly, but password seems to be lost.

Also tried use `vault.RetrieveAll();` method and make my `PasswordVault` as a static field inside my class - the same results.

Its really very weird.Password is not empty when it is saved, but its always empty.

Does anybode also faced with this issue? Can someone suggest something please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your retrieving code you are creating a new object of PasswordVault class so it is bound to be empty. make your PasswordVault object global and then try to set and retrieve the values .

Comment: @Mainak, as I wrote in my question, I tried to use it as a static field inside my wrapper class - it does not really matter. Moreover, I got the right `Vault` object - I can retrieve credentials. The problem is that inside credentials object login is present (what was actually saved) but the password is empty.P.S. I use MSDN docs for it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker

Comment: Stupid thing, but have you checked that `password` is not empty when saving?

Comment: @schumi1331, yes, there is a check for that before save

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Each object returned will have the proper resource and user name, but it will not include the password.

For more info, see Remark of the [PasswordVault.FindAllByResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.findallbyresource.aspx).

We should be able to use the [`PasswordCredential.RetrievePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential.retrievepassword.aspx) method to populate the password for the credential. After the operation returns successfully, we can get the password from the Password property.
For example:

```
 PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
 vault.Add(new PasswordCredential(key, login, password));
 var collection = vault.FindAllByResource(key).ToList();
 foreach (var item in collection)
 {
     item.RetrievePassword();
     var password = item.Password;
     Debug.WriteLine(password);
 }
```

Also we should be able to use [PasswordVault.Retrieve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.retrieve.aspx) to return credential that contains all the data.

For example:

```
PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
vault.Add(new PasswordCredential(key, login, password));
var pass = vault.Retrieve(key, login);
Debug.WriteLine(pass.Password);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it really works now! You made my day :)